# Google Sheets QUERY function

Tags: arrays, function, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I'm trying to create a query function that will average the numbers in columns B, C and D, based on what's in column f

example:

```
buckape 1000    10  1000    defense e6vowe0
aiden   500 9   900 defense e6vowe0
faxyst  400 8   800 defense e6vowe0
lumi    300 4   500 defense e6vowe0
refresh 200 2   400 defense e6vowe0
sahsook 100 1   200 defense e6vowe0
doltic  0   1   100 defense e6vowe0
```

I'm able to, currently, make it average out the rows grouped by column F like so:

```
=Query(A:F, "select F, avg(B), avg(C), avg(D) where F is not null and E='defense' group by F",-1)
```

which, in turn, results in my averages displayed by ID (which is good)

```
event ID    avg heal    avg kills   avg damage
e6vowe0     357.14      5.00        557.14
hfgk3og0    514.29      5.29        814.29
```

but, I'm struggling to get it to (in hopefully the same formula) also divide each original number (i.e B2 / average of B based on F), then repeating the process for columns C and D as well.

Hope this made sense, hope someone out here knows the query function better than I do. Thank you

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,{A2:A, B2:D/QUERY(QUERY(A:F, 
 "select avg(B),avg(C),avg(D)
  where F is not null 
    and E='defense' 
  group by F", 0), "offset 1", 0)}))
```

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E="defense", {A2:A, B2:D/
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(F2:F, QUERY(QUERY(A:F, 
 "select F,avg(B),avg(C),avg(D)
  where F is not null  
    and E='defense' 
  group by F", 0), "offset 1", 0), {2,3,4}, 0))}, ))
```

[image]

Comment: This  works, except for when i put in more information. My idea is to have a lot of rows with these different values in B:D. 

When the same name is used more than once, the formula errors out, resulting in "different array sizes" for division.

https://pastebin.com/Q7ChpWcA

This would be the second table I want to put in, testing if it works

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired final result ?

Comment: I set up this example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zJLvPitKYj63mFmXq1UMiZA_4OzQ58f1jO9Sz9Xp8cY/edit?usp=sharing You can copy paste the second leaderboard (hfgk3og0) under the first to see the errors in the formula. I made an example of what I wanted through a sum of different formulas, but i'm hoping to be able to condense it to one

Comment: @inatater answer updated - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zlJoc-r6KY6_FnRHRWITD1u7TUWewRVc7PraKsYGKSM/edit#gid=1062458974

Comment: I feel like I should be paying you for this - you're awesome. Thank you